# Freemarker list without trim

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I want to render list of strings like this:

```
- First object
  - Second object
  - Third
- Etc
```

From java:

```
modelAndView.addObject("data", converted);
```

where 'converted' is ArrayList

If my .ftl file i use next code:

```
<#list data as d>
  <br>
  ${d}
</#list>
```

But list rendered without start spaces, like:

```
- First object
- Second object
- Third
- Etc
```

How i can disable removing start spaces?

**UPD**:

I think that i solved a problem.

```
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap">
<#list data as d>
    <br> ${d} <#t>
</#list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML by design ignores whitespace in many cases; this is not related to FreeMarker. And that it ignores whitespace is a good thing if you write templates, as controlling whitespace precisely in templates is a pain (if at all possible with keeping your sanity, as not all template languages have `#t` and such). You should use `<ul>` and `<li>` (and customize how the bullet looks with CSS, if you want to use `-`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For my issue very important that whitespaces will be rendered. And whitespaces count important too. But i am not web developer and i don't know how to do this correctly